# Crontab suppressing rsync logfile output

Tags: cron

I have a shell script being executed by my cron tab that runs a couple rsync commands.  When I run it from command line it writes the log file as expected but when run by the cron I don't get the log file.

Here is what I'm running.

```
rsync --log-file=noon_file_backup.log -urv -e ssh /var/www/html/ root@192.168.10.3:/var/devbackups/noon
```

Comment: Take a look into crontab or messages logfile - maybe the question is reported there.

Comment: Make sure the `cron user` has `write permission` in the directory holding the log as well as the log.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.  I've checked the log and the report for this script looks fine.

Dec 13 21:44:01 ubuntu CRON[23579]: (root) CMD (/var/devbackups/noonrsync.sh)

David, the user is root as it's transferring files to a remote server using a key.